# Problem with ToC in LyX

Tags: table-of-contents

I'm writing my thesis on LyX. My ToC looks like this:

[image]

Why are sections and sub-sections page numbers not aligned on the right but below each entry? I'd like to have them aligned on the right and I'd also like to have dotted lines.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,english]{article} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc} 
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2} 
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2} 
\usepackage{setspace} 
\onehalfspacing

\makeatletter
\pdfpageheight\paperheight 
\pdfpagewidth\paperwidth

\date{}
\makeatother
\usepackage{babel} 

\begin{document} 
    \tableofcontents{}

    \section{\textit{Introduction}\protect \\ }

    \section{\textit{Literature review}\protect \\ }

    \subsection{\textit{Optimal Corporate LP}\protect \\ } 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. Without knowing more details about your document it is nearly impossible to say anything.

Comment: I set article as document type and then I just selected enter TOC. It automatically generated what is in the image. It's the first time I use lyx and therefore I don't know what details you need.

Comment: That is definately not the way a default ToC looks, so you must have done some modifications. Edit: Have you added anything to the LaTeX preamble? How have you created the sections?

Comment: I swear all options are the default ones apart from A4 layout. I put \date{} in the preamble. As for sections, I chose numbered Sections in the menu instead of standard

Comment: Well, [then we need an example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4488/): make a copy of your file, remove as much content as possible without removing the problem (perhaps leave just a section heading, a subsection and the ToC). Then open the `.lyx` file in a text editor (e.g. Gedit, Notepad), copy the entire file, and paste it into your question.

Comment: One thing: remove all formatting, paragraph styles, horizontal space etc. you may have added to the section and subsection headings. If you want to change how those are typeset you should make a global change in the preamble, not change each one individually. The `titlesec` package is one option, for example by adding something like `\usepackage{titlesec} \titleformat*{\section}{\itshape\large\bfseries}` to the preamble.

Comment: After seeing the code, the specific mistake you've made here is to hit Ctrl+Enter instead of just Enter at the end of the section titles. That is what inserts `\protect \\`.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `\\`-command in your section-titles. This command stands for "new line" or more correctly for new paragraph. I think you do not need this there. If you want to keep it, you will have to define each title twice. A version for the title and a version for the ToC. This looks like `\section[title for ToC]{title}`.

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article} 
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc} % in most cases I would use \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  here.
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2} 
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2} 
\usepackage{setspace} 
\onehalfspacing

% if you want to italicize your titles, you should do it as follows:
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{\textit{#1}}
\titleformat{\subsection}
{\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{\textit{#1}}

\begin{document} 
    \tableofcontents

    \section{Introduction}  
    \section{Literature review} 
    \subsection{Optimal Corporate LP} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It is hardly good advise to add `\textit` inside `\section`, even if the OP does it in the original ;-)

Comment: @daleif true, I am searching for something better at the moment. I am not that fit in patching and that stuff. If you know a line to italicize all titles, just add it and I'll make it a CW.

Comment: `titlesec` would also be my guess for `article` (I usually use `memoir` for everything, has its own interface).

Comment: Ok, if I add that to the preamble I solve the problem and I get the image you posted. However, what should I do in the preamble of the original document? Sorry for my ignorance

Comment: Just compare which lines I deleted and which I added and do the same in your preamble. I am sorry, but I have never seen LyX. Don't know how do edit the preamble there. Maybe you just open it in an editor, do the edit and save is. Afterwords, you should open it in LyX again.

Comment: @Gio In LyX, add the five lines starting with `\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}` to Document --> Settings --> Preamble.